# Replace a boolean field in JSON with sed

Tags: json, awk, sed

I am trying to replace a boolean inside a JSON string using `sed`.

**STRING**: `"should-replace":false`

How would I use `sed` to replace the `false` with `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
sed '/should-replace/s/false/true/' f
```

Comment: How, using sed, would you change `true` to `false` and `false` to `true`?

Comment: @JamesBrown - I think the requirement was to change the `false` with `true` only not vise-versa :)

Comment: That was a follow-up question to satisfy my personal interest.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F: '/should-replace/{$2=($2=="false"?"true":"false")}1' file
"should-replace" true
```

Notice: `false` -> `true`, everything else (meant to mean `true`) -> `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward:

```
sed "s/\"should-replace\":false/\"should-replace\":true/g"
```